# jupyter notebook を、全てテキストベースで、読みやすい形に変換するには？

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter についての質問を、例えばここ StackOverflow に対して投稿しようとすると、 jupyter notebook (`.ipynb` ファイル) の内容を、 ascii 的に、いい感じにテキストに変換してくれるツールがあるといいなと思います。

特に、グラフを ascii ベースのテキストにコンバートするのは流石に無理だと思いますが、 notebook の Out として保存されている

- 普通の文字列アウトプット
- pandas のデータフレームテーブル

については、これらは ascii 的な表現が可能だろうし、コンバーターも記述しうると思っています。

#### 質問

- jupyter notebook (`.ipynb`ファイル) を、テキストベースの媒体に内容を記載するために、その中身を ascii テキストの出力でコンバートしたいです。これは、どうやったら実現できるでしょうか？
- 求めている変換結果は、 jupyter 上で notebook を見ている際の構成要素、つまり、 In と Out が、それぞれがプログラム・その出力結果とわかる形で、 ascii テキストで表現されているような、テキスト出力です。

Comment: [nbconvert: Convert Notebooks to other formats](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) で [Supported output formats](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#supported-output-formats) の HTML/Markdown/Ascii 形式あたりを試してみてはどうでしょう？ 他には [How can I edit Jupyter/IPython notebooks as text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38661210/9014308) で [mwouts/jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext)、[aaren/notedown](https://github.com/aaren/notedown)、Atom Pluginの [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) というのが紹介されています。

Answer (score 1):

nbconvert (https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) よく聞きますが, 使ったこと無いので別ツールの紹介。

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) も `.ipynb` を元に各種フォーマットへ変換できます。StackOverflowでは Markdownのサポートもあるので以下のように指定できます。

```sh
pandoc (Jupyterのファイル).ipynb -t markdown_strict -o out.md
```

出力形式のオプション `-t` で指定している `markdown_strict` 以外にも, `commonmark` などあるようです。

参考:
Pandoc MANUAL.html [一般的なオプション](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-options)

Answer (score 0):

[jupyter-notebookを起動せずに簡単にipynbファイルを開く方法](https://dev2prod.site/jupyter/ipynb-viewer/) で紹介されている方法の一つに、
[nbviewer.js](https://kokes.github.io/nbviewer.js/viewer.html) のデモページを使用するとブラウザ上で`.ipynb`をドラッグ＆ドロップするだけで中身をプレビューできるようです。